# Blender model completely white after exporting (.fbx)

Tags: materials, node-editor, export, texture-baking, vertex-colors

I'm pretty new to Blender and Unity (started yesterday), and I am having some trouble with something.

Basically, I want to use this model in Unity (pretty much transferring it from one game to another) but for some reason the model is going completely white after exporting as a .FBX file. You can see it is white in both 3D Viewer and Unity, so it looks to me like an issue on Blenders end? The textures and materials are porting over to Unity without any issues though.

Because of how the model works in Unity I can't just add new shaders to it because it affects all faces on that axis. I want to keep the individual colours of the surfaces.

Based on what I can find from sifting through the mountains on information online, I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right? I've tried so many different things, but I'm at a total lose here.

I'm happy to provide any and all files as necessary, including the original file being used in Blender, the .blend file, and the .FBX file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Blender]

[image: 3D Viewer]

[image: Unity]

Comment: what are those materials on your mesh? And how did you export it? Are you sure that your settings are default in export? Because you can easily try that if you add default cube, set its color in principled bsdf to red color, the fbx will be 100% surely with red color, If it won't there is something wrong set in your export or in your material

Comment: @MikoCG I used the export settings as outlined on this webpage:
https://blenderbasecamp.com/how-to-export-an-fbx-to-unity-from-blender-with-textures/

As for the materials on the mesh, I don't know. Like I mentioned above, the model is actually from another game. That game lets you export your creations as a .glb file to use in other programs like Blender, which is what I am doing.

Comment: okay can you share your blend file with that glb or glb itself?

Comment: @MikoCG I've included the .glb, .blend, and .fbx files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jB-XxTKBp7FbvQiRujo8sXmMj3SCedc9?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, you are using Vertex colours, that's something different than regular color, check these sources : (Unfortunately I don't have unity on workstation so I cannot check it myself) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312958/showing-a-model-with-vertex-painted-colours-in-unity and this https://forum.unity.com/threads/import-vertex-color-from-blender.244293/ and this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82725/export-model-with-vertex-paint-to-fbx

Comment: @MikoCG thank you so much! One of the threads you linked to had a YouTube video link which, in which a guy created and shared a script for vertex shaders. So now the colour is showing up! My only problem now is the script doesn't contain the normals, so the studs have disappeared. Thank you anyway!